# ConEmu / cmder last line of shell getting hidden / scrolled beneath bottom

Tags: shell, cmd.exe, scrolling, conemu, cmder

I don't know if I've described this well, but the bottom line of the console keeps getting scrolled beneath the bottom. I imagine some setting I've tweaked caused this, but I can't figure out which one.  Below is a screenshot illustrating what I mean.

[image: Screenshots Displaying Missing Prompt]

The 'bad' view on the right side of the image is scrolled to the bottom, and it's a little hard to see, but the prompt has scrolled below the bottom of the screen and there is no way to get it to appear again, except:

1. Clearing the Screen with `cls` or `clear` depending on shell
2. The position sometimes toggles on minimize/maximize of ConEmu window.  Sometimes this fixes the problem; sometimes it introduces the problem

Fairly annoying.  Any thoughts?

**Update:** (*Adding Build Info*)

- ConEmu build 150310
- Clink v0.4 [`git:c13aaf`]
- git version 2.4.5.windows.1 *portable git*
- cmder v1.1.3

I think those are all the relevant involved components.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Not really sure - it just seems to 'happen' sometimes.  There are two contributing events that seem to initiate this happening most often - they are:

- Running a command with longer than console output, e.g. `dir /a %windir%\system32` *I have long buffer output checked in the setting - was at 300 - changed to 150 - no difference*
- Minimizing/Restoring ConEmu window.  As I said above, sometimes this fixes the existing problem.  Sometimes this causes the problem.

Comment: 1. Old build. 2. Absence of repro steps.

Comment: @Maximus - You're saying it is an old build?  Or I should check?  Repro steps?  Screenshot of settings?

Comment: At least, you have to name the build number and repro steps.

Comment: Build numbers of all used software: ConEmu, clink, git, etc.

Comment: @Maximus.  See update.  Let me know if you need more info - or if you want me to move this to github.

Comment: Both ConEmu and clink are too old. Update them.

Comment: @Maximus - I've updated both and still happens.  I assume it's setting I've changed, but don't know which one.

Comment: With StatusBar hidden nobody may say what happens on your side. Attach you settings at least, or try to run "ConEmu -basic".

Comment: did you manage to sort this? I'm seeing the same problem. The last character of the status bar of tmux is not shown :/

Comment: @lucid_dreamer - It just sort of stopped.  I don't know whether it was an version update or what, but it's not happening anymore.  Sorry can't offer more.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. what conemu version are you on if I can ask?

Comment: @lucid_dreamer - I'm currently using 191012 preview.

Comment: mhh.. 180626 here... Time for a test.

Answer (score 3):

**Possible Cause**

This seems to have happened for me with the following

- Window size: Height: 100%
- Restore to active monitor
- (I also have quake-style enabled but don't know that that would affect it)

**Work-around**

Setting Height to 98% or something seems to have fixed this.

**Additional Thoughts**

I noticed on the extra monitor the scroll bar did not extend all the way to the bottom of the console.  This lead me to believe it has something to do with the height / buffering.  When I set height back to 100% it did not revert though to being "wrong".  If I notice it again I'll nab one and update this post.